# How to prove `forall m n : nat, m == n -> m = n`?

Tags: coq, tactic, coq-mathcomp, coq-ssreflect

I am learning Coq with ssreflect. Just to understand things, I've proved `forall a b : bool, a == b -> a = b` but I can't figure out how to prove `forall m n : nat, m == n -> m = n`. I've tried using the `elim` tactic first on `m`, then on `n`, but in the end I was left with a subgoal I couldn't prove. I've tried `destruct m` and then `destruct n` but the result was the same.

---

A minimal working example to try to prove this is

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma eqn_impl_eq (m n : nat) (m_eqn_n : is_true (m == n)) : m = n.
Proof.
Admitted.
```

It uses mathcomp library though.

Comment: I'm a beginner with Coq. I'm trying to follow along with this example, but I couldn't figure out exactly what to import to prove `forall m n : nat , m == n -> m = n`. In particular, I'm not sure what to import to get `==` in scope. Can you please include an MCVE?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Induction can be used via `elim` tactic on both `m` and `n`, like this: `elim=> [| m1 hm] [| n1 hn]`. That results in 4 cases:

- `0, 0` case is `trivial`
- `0, S m1` case can be solved by contradiction via `discriminate` tactic applied to the boolean equality
- same for `S n1, 0` case
- `S n1, S m1` case can be solved by proving `n1 = m1` first by applying induction hypothesis for both n and m. `S m1 = S m1` can then be proved by `f_equal`.

Comment: I don't see how to get `n1 = m1` from the two induction hypotheses in the last case.

Comment: The induction hypotheses are `forall n, m1 == n -> m1 = n` and `S m1 == S n1` but the latter is definitionally equal to `m1 == n1` so the former can be applied to `n1` and the latter.

Comment: I get different induction hypotheses: `forall n0 : nat, (n0 == n -> n0 = n) -> n0.+1 == n -> n0.+1 = n` and `m == n.+1 -> m = n.+1`, while the goal is `m.+1 == n.+1 -> m.+1 = n.+1`.

Comment: When doing induction, you can put arguments to the local context instead of keeping them in the goal. SSReflect provides a convenient syntax for that: `elim=> [| m1 hm] [| n1 hn].`

Comment: What a weird induction scheme you've proposed. In it, we start at `(0, 0)`, can move any number of times to the right (from `(x, 0)` to `(S x, 0)`) OR any number of times up (from `(0, y)` to `(0, S y)`), and then any number of times along the main diagonal (from `(x, y)` to `(S x, S y)`). How did `elim=> [| m1 hm] [| n1 hn].` turn into this? Is it possible to use different induction schemes as easily? Btw, it works, thanks.

Comment: `elim=> [| m1 hm] [| n1 hn].` does nothing special. It's almost the same as `elim=> [| m1 hm]; elim=> [| n1 hn].` The resulting induction scheme depends on how you use `hm` and `hn`.

Answer (score 4):

SSReflect builds upon the relationship between booleans (`m == n`) and proposition (`m = n`); this is called reflection, hence the name. You can go from one to the other using the `/eqP` construct. In your case, one simple proof is thus to simply call for this functionality:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma eqn_impl_eq (m n : nat) (m_eqn_n : is_true (m == n)) : m = n.
Proof. exact/eqP. Qed.
```

You can learn more about this in the documentation, for instance this [tutorial](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00407778/document)